# Is it possible in Vue to programatically wrap an element or component with a transition using a custom directive or render function?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

To make code more simple/clean for me and my designers, I'd like to be able to do something like below. Is it possible - using a custom directive or render function to implement this with a simple attribute?

This would really help separating animation from structure and functionality, which I think could be helpful in many cases. I figure render functions can easily wrap an element with other HTML elements, but can they wrap elements (or components) with custom Vue transitions?

This:

```
<template>
        <my-component custom-transition></mycomponent>
</template>
```

Becomes this:

```
<template>
    <custom-transition>
        <my-component></mycomponent>
    </custom-transition>
</template>
```

Or maybe bring it up on Github?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is very doable: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Single-Elements-Components

Answer (score 0):

A Vue forum member provided a great solution for me in [this thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/is-it-possible-to-programatically-wrap-an-element-or-component-with-a-transition-using-a-custom-directive-or-render-function/63462/2) using dynamic components. Happy!